# Cannot install Nvidia digits

Tags: apt, nvidia, software-installation

I am trying to install Nvidia digits in my ubuntu 14.04.

I tried to install digits by entering the command

```
sudo apt-get install digits
```

but I am getting error as given below

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package digits
```

I tried updating the package list and upgrading the packages

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

But could not fix the problem

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-machine-learning.list`? Did you run `sudo apt-get update` before `sudo apt-get install digits`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvidia Digits isn't available in Ubuntu's default repositories. You can however add a PPA (see [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some “red flags” to watch out for?](/q/35629/175814)). The [official installation instructions](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/blob/master/docs/UbuntuInstall.md) are:

> ### Prerequisites
>
> You need an NVIDIA driver ([details and instructions](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/blob/master/docs/InstallCuda.md#driver)).
>
> Run the following commands to get access to some package repositories:
>
> ```sh
> # Access to CUDA packages
> CUDA_REPO_PKG=cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_7.5-18_amd64.deb
> wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1404/x86_64/${CUDA_REPO_PKG} -O /tmp/${CUDA_REPO_PKG}
> sudo dpkg -i /tmp/${CUDA_REPO_PKG}
> rm -f /tmp/${CUDA_REPO_PKG}
>
> # Access to Machine Learning packages
> ML_REPO_PKG=nvidia-machine-learning-repo-ubuntu1404_4.0-2_amd64.deb
> wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1404/x86_64/${ML_REPO_PKG} -O /tmp/${ML_REPO_PKG}
> sudo dpkg -i /tmp/${ML_REPO_PKG}
> rm -f /tmp/${ML_REPO_PKG}
>
> # Download new list of packages
> sudo apt-get update
> ```
>
> ### Installation
>
> Now that you have access to all the packages you need, installation is simple.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install digits
> ```
>
> Through package dependency chains, this installs `digits`, `caffe-nv`, `torch7-nv`, `libcudnn` and many more packages for you automatically.

The Apt source lines added by those two packages are:

```
deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1404/x86_64/ /
deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1404/x86_64/ /
```

Comment: I have performed those commands before sudo apt-get install digits

Comment: I think the error is with the ubuntu package installer

Comment: Possible but much less likely than a bug in Nvidias packages.

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: Could you please  share the repo link that gets added to sources.list when executing the two commands     CUDA_REPO_PKG=cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_7.5-18_amd64.deb
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1404/x86_64/${CUDA_REPO_PKG} -O /tmp/${CUDA_REPO_PKG}
sudo dpkg -i /tmp/${CUDA_REPO_PKG}
rm -f /tmp/${CUDA_REPO_PKG}

Comment: ML_REPO_PKG=nvidia-machine-learning-repo-ubuntu1404_4.0-2_amd64.deb
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1404/x86_64/${ML_REPO_PKG} -O /tmp/${ML_REPO_PKG}
sudo dpkg -i /tmp/${ML_REPO_PKG}
rm -f /tmp/${ML_REPO_PKG}

Comment: See the update to my question.